Using MySQL.Data with C# while not making a MySql Connection for transactions
This question is similar to this one: Using MySql.Data with C# while not making a MySqlConnection
Basically, I can see in the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-pooling.html it says to avoid creating a MySqlConnection object, however, it doesn't say how to handle transactions.
Is there a similar api that is supposed to be used instead of creating a MySqlConnection object as detailed here? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/latest/api/data_api/MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction.html

Use MySqlConnector class from NuGet.

This is a legacy project that we're trying to update the MySql.Data library to a newer version. So we are trying to avoid as many breaking changes as possible. I would prefer not to have to change to a completely different library

Why you ask for "similar api" - this is the necessary api.

I'm looking for a different api within MySql.Data that allows you to utilize transactions while also following their directive of not creating a MySqlConnection object directly.

@Corey if you want to avoid breaking changes do move to the truly open source and supported MySqlConnector. Oracle barely maintains MySql.Data and even refused to fix many serious bugs. Check the very long list of bugs that are fixed in MySqlConnector

As Bradley Grainger points out in his answer, there is nothing wrong with creating your own as outlined in your last link.  The key to the warning in the documentation is "...globally accessible...and reuse..." because it circumvents the connection pooling.

The documentation doesn't say to "avoid creating a MySqlConnection object" as a blanket rule.
It says:

"Do not create a globally accessible instance of MySqlConnection and then manually open and close it." This is good advice.
"One approach that simplifies things is to avoid creating a MySqlConnection object manually. Instead, use the overloaded methods that take a connection string as an argument." This is a recommendation for a possible approach you can use when a special-purpose API has a method that takes a connection string and does its work.

However, you don't have to do that, and there's nothing wrong with new MySqlConnection(connectionString).
The other documentation you linked to (here) shows a perfectly acceptable way of opening a connection and starting a transaction:
using MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnString);
myConnection.Open();
// Start a local transaction
using MySqlTransaction myTrans = myConnection.BeginTransaction();
using MySqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
// do your work here...
myTrans.Commit();

